# Convert linq with All to SQL

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql

I have tables A, B and C

B is related to A as many-to-one

I want to find all A where C is full subset of B.

Follwing LINQ query (pseudocode) is representing what I want to get.

```
class A
{
    public B[] Bs { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

private static IEnumerable<A> Search(C[] C, A[] A)
{
    return from a in A
            where C.All(c => a.Bs.Any(b => SomeCondition(b, c)))
            select a;
}

private static bool SomeCondition(B b, C c)
{
    //There we comparing B and C
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I have following table structure

```
A ( a_ID INT PRIMARY KEY )
B ( b_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, a_ID INT, Text NVARCHAR(MAX) )
C ( c_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Text NVARCHAR(MAX) )
```

I need to get ALL A, where B matches all C.

Example

```
A | a_ID |
  | 1    |
  | 2    |
  | 3    |

B | b_ID | a_ID | Text  |
  | 1    | 1    | Cat   |
  | 2    | 1    | Dog   |
  | 3    | 1    | Rabbit| 
  | 4    | 2    | Cat   | 
  | 5    | 2    | Cat   | -- B can contain duplicates
  | 6    | 2    | Rabbit|

C | c_ID | Text |
  | 1    | Cat  |
  | 2    | Dog  |
```

Output

```
| a_ID |
| 1    |
```

Comment: @tmack it is a pseudo code.

Comment: It's not enough information to understand the question. If it would compile, it probably would be.

Comment: Can you provide table's DDL and desired output?

Comment: what linq provider are you using? Linq 2 Sql? EF?

Comment: @andri I'm not using linq provider, it is an pseudo-code of what I need to write in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out how to make it.

Assuming that `x=>x.All(e => predicate(e))` can be converted to `x=>!x.Any(e => !predicate(e))`

We can convert our original expression to following one

```
from a in A
where !C.Any(c => !a.Bs.Any(b => SomeCondition(b, c)))
select a;
```

Any can be converted to SQL using `exists` keyword

I will assume that `SomeCondition` is just equal

First convert `!a.Bs.Any(b => SomeCondition(b, c))` to SQL

```
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM B b
        WHERE a.a_id = b.a_id -- a will be added later
          AND c.Text = b.Text -- c will be added later
)
```

Next convert `!C.Any(c => !a.Bs.Any(b => SomeCondition(b, c)))`

```
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM C c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM B b
        WHERE a.a_id = b.a_id -- a will be added later
          AND c.Text = b.Text
    )
)
```

And finally the whole expression

```
SELECT * FROM A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM C c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM B b
        WHERE a.a_id = b.a_id
          AND c.Text = b.Text
    )
)
```

Now we can do some optimizations

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED3:** count distinct c_id

```
SELECT b.a_id
  FROM b
  JOIN c ON b.Text = c.Text
GROUP BY b.a_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct c.c_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C)
```

Output:

```
| A_ID |
--------
|    1 |
```

Here is a **[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/886b6/26)**

Comment: It will select A where any B in C. Not all.

Comment: Thanks @peterm is there any posibility to avoid having count(*)?

Comment: Actually join with A here is not required

Comment: Fair enough `JOIN` with A is redundant. Updated the answer. No you can't avoid `COUNT` in my version of query. But it executes once and it's fast. BTW If `C.Text` is `NULL`able than you need to use `SELECT COUNT(Text) FROM C`

Comment: Fixed by COUNT(distinct c.c_id)

Comment: Ok. It makes sense. But COUNT(c.c_id) in subquery makes no sense if it's a PK. Since we join by `Text` IMHO you should either use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(Text)`. It's highly unlikely that you have an entry in `C` that has `NULL` in `c_id`.